# What does this hand gesture of fighter jet pilots mean?

Tags: fighter, jet

I am trying to understand more of the gestures fighter jet pilot use. I have seen this gesture many times:

[image: Fighter pilot making a hand gesture]

Does anyone know what this gesture mean? Are there any good resources about the gestures used by fighter jets? I can't find information about this.

Comment: It is interesting that we have a tag for "radio-communications", but not one for other forms of communications.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is the signal to perform a fuel check.  (Actually: "*How much fuel have you?*")

The hand mimics drinking from a bottle, and when given by a formation flight lead it is intended to prompt the wingman to respond with a number of fingers to indicate fuel remaining in hundreds of pounds.

There are several pages of inter-flight signals in table form found in the NAVAIR 00-80T-113, "AIRCRAFT SIGNALS NATOPS MANUAL".  (*For US Navy, the USAF likely has a similar document...*)  A copy can be found here:  [SIGNALS NATOPS](https://dokumen.tips/documents/aircraft-signals-natops-manual-navair-00-materialnavair113pdfaircraft-signals.html?page=1)

This particular signal is found on page 1-8 and is reproduced below.  (*Note - the pinky seen in the photo isn't specified, but is generally used to ensure that the signal isn't confused with a closed fist*)
[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for your clear answer!

Comment: I see that the NATOPS literally writes it that way, but how is "How much fuel have you?" not incorrect grammar? Is that some phraseology quirk I'm unaware of?

Comment: @MrArsGravis it's not incorrect but sort of old fashioned. see also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/use-of-have-in-questions-do-you-have-or-have-you

Comment: I'd looked it up in a the Oxford Reference Grammar in the meantime and it also concurred that it is still a somewhat accepted form in BrE. If this Ngram is to be believed, it actually seems to have been the dominant form, at least in written English, up to the mid-20th century (I was expecting it to have died out a century earlier): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have+you+a%2CDo+you+have+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3

Comment: It sounds better if you ask in a Yoda voice...

Comment: With the pinkie out, it means "Is it time for tea?"  Used by British armed forces.

Comment: @WayneConrad Are they required to signal back "yes"?